# Google analytics track outbound links

Tags: google-analytics

Simple question:

Im trying to track outbound links on my homepage. Problem: I only see the events in the realtime section. Does someone know where its stored? Im storing it with the following code:

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {'hitCallback':
  function () {
     document.location = url;
   }
  });
}
```

Comment: You will find this in the "events" report in the behavior section of the GA menu (will take some time to show up), and also in the events sections of the realtime report.

Comment: Thanks! So it just takes some time to be there? How long does usually take? Im waiting for maybe 1 hour now.

Comment: According to Google it may take 24 hours (usually it's quicker than that, especially on small sites. However it should show up in the realtime reports immediatley).

Comment: Okay thanks. Yeah in the realtime reports they are there immediately. Thanks for your help

Comment: Google says that it should show up under Behavior > Events. It's interesting you mention this though, because I don't see it there either. I'm trying to track outbound links on [culturehog.com](http://culturehog.com) so let me know if you get this resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  said in comments.

You can find events stored in `Behavior->Events` section of the GA menu. It will take some time to show up - up to 24h